# Can't see data from db in my listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I was trying to display my data dynamically in a listview. I first insert data into db then displaying them in listview. I don't understand why but I created db and listview, it doesn't show data when I try to display it.

I'm getting data from `EditText` fields but I insert and display the data in another `activity`. I first thought I coludn't get the data from first activity, but I'm sure that I wrote the right code.

The field for the data in listview always empty. I should create a new entry when I press a "Add" button. I can see that it creates a new row in the list with a new id but the rest is empty.

Why I don't see data there? This is how I get data and put inside db and list:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

   String name = "";
   String email = ""; 
   String phone = "";
   String address = "";

   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
        name = extras.getString("name");
        email = extras.getString("email");
        phone = extras.getString("phone");
        address = extras.getString("address");
   }


   listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

   mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
   mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

   cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

   String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_NAME, SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL,SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_PHONE, SQLiteAdapter.COLUMN_ADDRESS};

   int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.text3, R.id.text4};

   cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

   listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
   mySQLiteAdapter.insert(name,email,phone,address);
   updateList();

 }
```

This is my main activity

```
  Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
      EditText nametext = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.NameText);
      final String nt = nametext.getText().toString();
      EditText emailtext = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.MailText);
      final String et = emailtext.getText().toString();
      EditText phonetext = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.PhoneText);
      final String pt = phonetext.getText().toString();
      EditText addresstext = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.AddressText);
      final String at = addresstext.getText().toString();


        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("name",nt);
                myIntent.putExtra("email",et);
                myIntent.putExtra("phone",pt);
                myIntent.putExtra("address",at);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

          });
```

Here is my queueAll function:

```
 public Cursor queueAll(){
 String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, COLUMN_NAME,
 COLUMN_EMAIL,COLUMN_PHONE,COLUMN_ADDRESS};

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,

null, null, null, null, null);

return cursor;

}
```

Comment: are you sure about getting data from db..???

Comment: could you send code that is   queueAll() methods body statements?

Comment: When I insert a data into db, it calls update() function to show all rows with the new one. I maybe placed insert function wrong. I will check that. But I'm sure that this insert function adds new data into db